# why Swiper JS inital loading shows a single slider?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, swiper.js

I am trying to use the swiper js library : https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

It works fine but I have problem with initial loading ..its a carousel with multiple multiple carousel items. But when I load the carousel it loads the first slider item first, which covers the entire screen. Then it starts loading the other carousel items. I am using it in elementor, WordPress

I tried using below code as documented. I am using Jquery

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/150-freemode.html

What could I be possibly doing wrong for this case?

update:
i found that setting max-width for the swiper-wraper can fix the issue..any way to set that based on colomn count?

Comment: The problem isn't really clear to me. What do you expect to happen? Does it shows 2 carousels instead of 1?

Comment: @Kielstra as seen in the link..it loads the first slider then loads the other slider.. http://dev.geekygreenowl.online/post-grid/

Comment: @Kielstra i expect to load the carousel smoother ..direct loading without being the first slider item covering the entire carousel

Comment: Not sure if you can do much about that, since that's how the Swiper library evaluates the page.

Comment: @Kielstra but in their demo, it seems to load very smoothly?

Comment: @Kielstra I solved it by setting `max-width: max-content;`

Comment: @Kielstra But still require some method to calculate it

Comment: To calculate what exactly?

Comment: The same issue happens to me when trying to build / initialize a Swiper slider by looping through items (slides) coming from a "stringyfied" localStorage array... The Slider is initiated but the fist slide comes first and then a second later the other sliders are rendered...